# Soft Dynamic shadow in Unity iOS

Tags: ios, shader, unity-game-engine

I need to display a soft dynamic shadow of a rigid body in unity for iOS platform.

What i have done so far is i am able to do dynamic shadow using a light direction and taking a projection of the rigid body on the plane and then using a texture, i am getting a shadow effect. But don't know what to do to make them soft at the edges.

Any suggestions or reference link will be of great help.

Thanks.